# Prove that a shape must be a rhombus using rules of coordinate geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

Quadrilateral ABCD has points A (0,0) B (a,b) C (a+b,a+b) D (b,a). Prove it is a rhombus for any values of a and b.

I have tried to solve this by saying that since points A and C both have equal x and y coordinates, that this means all 4 sides are equal etc. However, this doesn't sound correct to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Just calculate the $4$ sides and show that $\,AB=BC=CD=DA=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $m(PQ)$ as the slope of PQ.

By inspection, 
$m(AB)=m(CD)=\dfrac ba$
and 
$m(BC)=m(AD)=\dfrac ab$, 
i.e. opposite sides are parallel.

Also, by inspection, $m(AC)\cdot m(BD)=1\cdot (-1)=-1$
i.e. diagonals are perpendicular.

Hence $ABCD$ is a rhombus. $\blacksquare$